# Should I use bitwise operations for m-d arrays rather than integer types when working with only 1s and 0s (considering CPU cache)?

Tags: arrays, multithreading, multidimensional-array, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I found an interesting [snippet](https://bitbucket.org/BWerness/voxel-automata-terrain/src/master/ThreeState3dBitbucket.pde) written in Java that operates on three-dimensional arrays. I am a bit concerned about its performance because larger arrays (1<<14 and more) seem to one fail to clean up the memory and two take ages running only on a single thread.

The first thing that came to my mind was to compress the types - it can operate only on 1s and 0s, so integers of 4 bytes seem like overkill (unless Java does something smart to reduce them automatically).

Would porting this to C and trying to rebuild this logic with bitwise operations seem like a promising endeavor? Or would the potential benefits (saved CPU cycles) be lost by CPU cache misses for example?

Comment: Can you please quote the snippet in your question, as the link points to a website with a separate user agreement? Not 100% sure about the JVM these days, but processor architecture tends not to be optimised for boolean variable types--you might find working with bytes, short integers, etc. faster. Instead might be an idea to transform the algorithm so that it works on n-byte data, where n is optimal for the target platform (as opposed to on bits).

Comment: Interesting, yes that was my 'gut feeling' as well, that optimizing for something below the standard word size will be hard. I don't have much experience with low-level programming, but I would be surprised if there was no reliable optimization strategy here. Not sure about the link though, do you mean something like [this](https://bitbucket.org/BWerness/voxel-automata-terrain/raw/9818871800e936e16de08d608f70298c4f6b4e0d/ThreeState3dBitbucket.pde)?

Comment: Been a while since I programmed with JAVA, but probably still uses a garbage collector to clean-up no-longer needed occupied memory. Porting to C could help but then you would have to manually code the "garbage collection". Such manual intervention can sometimes be beneficial when wanting to optimise. Not sure what you mean by CPU cache misses. Why do you think you might get such a problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the manual memory management hurdles in C and I'm looking forward to it. In terms of the cache misses I sense that standard types will be somehow more easily recognized by the CPU cache than manually manipulated bitsets if that makes sense. As you said CPUs are probably tuned for standard types and this would be my guess how going around it might get back at me.

Comment: Don't think it is possible to do computations on data of size less than the word size. I don't think cache misses will be an issue. The computer will somehow try to do what you tell it, in its own terms, in multiples of bytes (normally). At the moment you're worried about space wastage (4 bytes instead of a bit). Compressing the data into bit-sets that are some multiple of the word size, should allow more data to be cached in the CPU, meaning more cache hits (rather than misses) [I would have thought].

Comment: I see, that's good to know. Just to be clear I didn't mean addressing single bits in memory, but rather to translate arithmetic operations to bitwise operations on standard bitset types. If this didn't incur any cache penalties that's only for the better. If so, I need to find some examples ideally something like loops with bit manipulations on m-d arrays.